# Is it not possible to have a check constraint reference a column that also has a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table, check-constraints, mysql-8.0

I'm on MySQL 8 trying to add a check constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD CHECK (
    (`column_a` IS NULL AND `column_b` IS NOT NULL) OR
    (`column_a` IS NOT NULL AND `column_b` IS NULL)
);
```

but I keep getting [this error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_check_constraint_clause_using_fk_refer_action_column):

> Column 'column_b' cannot be used in a check constraint 'table_chk_1': needed in a foreign key constraint 'table_ibfk_2' referential action.

I can't find any reference to this error anywhere else on the internet and I don't understand what the problem is.
Both `column_a` and `column_b` are also foreign keys to other tables and they are both nullable. I just want to make sure that each row in `table` has either a reference via `column_a` or via `column_b`.

What is the cause of this error?

---

#### What have I tried

I've tried to drop the foreign keys, add the check constraints and it succeeds. Then if I add the foreign key back to `column_b` I still get the same error.

Comment: It seems to be referring specifically to a referential action. That would be something like `ON DELETE CASCADE` being specified in an FK.

Comment: Plese share the `create table` statement for your table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [a documented behavior](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html):

> Foreign key referential actions (`ON UPDATE`, `ON DELETE`) are prohibited on columns used in `CHECK` constraints. Likewise, `CHECK` constraints are prohibited on columns used in foreign key referential actions.

So you need to choose between having a referential action on your column, or having a check constraint. Alternatively, you can keep the referential action and implement the check logic using triggers (or keep the check constraint and implement the referential action in a trigger!).

Comment: Oh yeah, apparently this was caused by a `ON UPDATE CASCADE` for `column_b`. Hmm, I'm not sure I understand the rationale behind this behavior? Do you have any insights perhaps?

Comment: @ShoeDiamente Running into this same problem myself. Super annoying. MySQL has many aspects with questionable `rationale`, and I guess we just have to live with it. :(

Comment: @ShoeDiamente, did you end up using a trigger? In hindsight, any idea why this limitation might have been put in place?